# swift rest api no error with code but simulator show nothing

Tags: swift

Swift doesn't show any errors, but the simulator doesn't show anything.
I want to use kakao map rest api 'Search for places by keyword'.
But I don't think it is simulator problem. Because I opened a new file and turned on the simulator, but nothing came up.
I think it is error of code.

Please help me

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


struct Place: Decodable{
    let placeName: String
    let roadAdressName: String
    let longitudeX: String
    let latitudeY: String
    }

class dokseosil: UIViewController {
    
    private var resultList=[Place]()
    
    func keywordSearch(keyword: String, page: Int) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "KakaoAK {kakao rest api app key}"
        ]
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "query": keyword,
            "page": 15,
            "size": 10
        ]
        
        AF.request("https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/local/search/keyword.json", method: .get,
                   parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
        .responseDecodable(of: Place.self) { response in
            switch response.result {
                
            case .success(let value):
                
                if let detailsPlace = JSON(value)["documents"].array{
                    for item in detailsPlace{
                        let placeName = item["place_name"].string ?? ""
                        let roadAdressName = item["road_address_name"].string ?? ""
                        let longitudeX = item["x"].string ?? ""
                        let latitudeY = item["y"].string ?? ""
                        self.resultList.append(Place(placeName: placeName,
                                                     roadAdressName: roadAdressName, longitudeX: longitudeX, latitudeY: latitudeY))
                    }
                }
                
                print("\(self.resultList[0].placeName)")
                print("\(self.resultList[1].placeName)")
                print("\(self.resultList[2].placeName)")
                
                case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }
}
```

Comment: So where do you call the keywordSearch function and where do you update the UI? Also be aware that your print statements will make the app crash if resultList is empty.

Comment: You need to provide details about what is actually happening. Is the `keywordSearch` method even being called? If so, how far does it get? Have you used the debugger to step through the code?